# A person who is adamant because he knows he is right, without being rude

Tags: pejorative-language, single-word-requests

At my workplace, my senior, who is senior than me by age, experience and knowledge is always right.

I want to tell (admit/appraise) him that, I do what he says and do not put my POV because at the end of conversation he will emerge as correct with all facts and examples and convince all of us in meeting.

I don't want to use stubborn, adamant or any other rude word because he is never rude but polite.

**Edit:** I want to add more maybe it is more  or less similar to what I wrote, still I think it would bring us more closer to that word.

1. He doesn't easily surrender to what anyone says in meeting and put facts across to in support of his point.
2. Generally it becomes kind of interactive debate session and he appears to be winner in the end.

**Steadfast:**

> He could come up as "Sorry, what did you say" and
>
> I go like "blah blah.."
>
> He again, "No dear, I am not that person" another debate started.

**Authoritative, Self-reliant or Self-Righteous**:

> He could come up as "Oh no dear, I don't want to act as Authority, authoritative here, I am just putting facts on the table".

I am looking for word that people would accept, without any explanation/after-thoughts.

Comment: 'Assertive' in my opinion carries overtones of pushiness, whereas 'assured' may not be forceful enough.

Comment: What's went with calling him **correct**?

Comment: @TusharRaj I think not a dup: The question you link is about somebody who always *thinks* he is right (and since no other information is given, we must assume that this is not always true). That is almost the opposite of this question.

Comment: Just call him *sensei* ;-).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: The top answer there offers plenty of suggestions for both cases. I love your `sensei` suggestion though.

Comment: The only danger with sensei - which is indeed very popular in the US - is that it leans to the humorous.  Other common such phrases are *"dude, you are the master"* or *"boss .. we're not worthy"* (from the famous film originally) and so on.  As with any extreme language subtleties, of course there is a slight danger of leaning towards being humorous rather than totally awestruck and sincere. This is a rich field of language enquiry in the US, since (perhaps due to the (a) germanic and (b) slavery & genocide origins of the country) there's a high usage of non-sarcastic devotional language...

Comment: (... compare the UK, where everyone from the Pythons to Churchill just rips holes in and snorts at authority.)  So yeah you have many choices, all good ones.

Answer (score 6):

The word ***authoritative*** has meanings which can be combined to get the sense that you are looking for.

ODO:

> **[authoritative](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/authoritative)**
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Able to be trusted as being accurate or true; reliable
>
> ‘Clinic staff may be seen as authoritative sources of prevention
> information.’
>
> **2** Commanding and self-confident; likely to be respected and obeyed:
>
> ‘his voice was calm and authoritative’

---

**Addendum (courtesy of Joe Blow)**:

And the good news is,

> "The authority"

**is a commonplace catchphrase, often used in the US**.

If you say to your boss...

> Boss, you are the Authority, dude.

Your full sense is conveyed.

Examples of use ... "Here comes The Authority" (as he walks in to the room) or "We need to ask The Authority - our boss" (when a problem arises).

This phrase has that exact "pumped-up / sports-crowd like" feel that US audiences look for, or indeed need.  So, when you exclaim, "Boss, you are The Authority!" it could well be followed by everyone in the room fistpumping, doing the deep "yeah", and then chanting U-S-A-U-S-A.

Note that indeed it is used in a number of marketing slogans; "XYZ Sports stores .. the Sports Authority" and so on.

Use in a marketing tagline is the ultimate proof positive (in the USA) that the phrase is absolutely - utterly - wholesome; spotlessly positive; spostlessly politically correct; and very broadly understood.  So, you're golden.

Comment: +1. However, I've rarely, if ever, seen the word being applied to a person; as opposed to a resource or an attitude. It might help if you provide some example sentences that suit the OP's requirement.

Comment: @TusharRaj  I've heard  "someone is an authority on" a specific subject

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, that's common enough. But somehow, "Clint is authoritative here in this project" doesn't seem to sit right. That's why I wanted some usage examples.

Comment: "Tom's answers/solutions/proposals are always authoritative" sounds good to me. As does ["he is authoritative"](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22He+is+authoritative%22&start=10)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Hmm. I'm not saying it's wrong. ODO's example sentences did use the word this way, but very few of them. I think it's a less common use of the word and the post could use some examples, like the ones you just provided, which sound good indeed.

Comment: **Authoritative** is the perfect answer. For example, I am indeed authoritative in my (many) areas of technical expertise, in my industry.  **HOWEVER, it's very true that most people are so dumb, they'd think the word is a smear, because it's an uncommon word and sounds 'officious'." You have to take this in to account.  Good news though, I have an answer...

Comment: @alwayslearning - I've **added an addendum** to your superb answer.  As always feel free to edit, unwind, whatever, cheers

Comment: @JoeBlow: Wish I could upvote again after reading your thoroughly entertaining addendum :)

Comment: "Boss, you are the Authority, dude." Less formally, "You da man".

Answer (score 3):

> ## [steadfast](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steadfast)
>
> :  firm in belief, determination, or adherence :  loyal

Steadfast is often used to describe storybook heroes — *[The Steadfast Tin Soldier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Steadfast_Tin_Soldier)* is a notable example — but the word is commonly understood, and appropriate here.

To call someone steadfast would always be a compliment, although its heroic tone might make someone chuckle.

#### Usage example

> I am impressed with how you handle the pressure to take unwise shortcuts. I only wish I could be so steadfast.

Answer (score 2):

You could say *Uncompromising*. This carries the sense of both strength and correctness, because one of the senses of a compromise is to accept lower standards than necessary. The problem is that if you call someone uncompromising in a debate, it means that they won't make any concessions.

Another word is *Exacting*. This means very precise, and also carries the sense of strength and correctness. Someone with exacting standards doesn't compromise, in the sense of settling for less than what is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your boss is determined and doesn't change his mind easily because he thinks he is right, which he always is.

You might then tell him, you think he has a **self-reliant** countenance.

> - [**self-reliant**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-reliant) (adj) - Reliant on one's own capabilities, judgment, or resources

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a single word (besides *sensei*, which may not be understood by people who have never been in a dojo or watched *Kung Fu Panda*), but I would call him a *tenacious and patient source of knowledge.* It's obvious that he is tenacious, and I'd call him patient to credit him for dealing with his junior colleagues who always challenge him and apparently keep being wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Self-righteous**

:convinced of one's own righteousness especially in contrast with the actions and beliefs of others. 
[Merriam-Webster's]

*He is so self-righteous talking about his religion it's not even worth going there in conversation.*

Answer (score 0):

I nominate [**doyen**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doyen):

> 1a :  the senior member of a body or group
>
> 1b :  a person **considered to be knowledgeable** or uniquely skilled **as a result of long experience in some field of endeavor**

<sub>(M-W)</sub>

It doesn't perfectly capture what you asked in the title, but I think it should work for you based on what you described in the post.

It acknowledges expertise and seniority without the (negative) connotations of (undue) authority or cockiness.